# Writing from IMFSourceReader to IMFSinkWriter stops after 2 or 3 seconds

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, ms-media-foundation

I'm trying to capture from a webcam source to a file using source reader in asynchronous mode.  It goes well for few seconds and video is recorded with 30 fps but then abruptly the FPS drops to 0.

I've tried enabling and disabling MF_SINK_WRITER_DISABLE_THROTTLING in SinkWriter.  For some reason, it seems to be blocking input.  Also, the method OnReadSample stops being called.

Here's the OnReadSample method:

```
EnterCriticalSection(&m_critsec);
if (SUCCEEDED(hrStatus))
{
    if (pSample)
    {
        if (audio)
        {
            WriteLogFile(L"audio: @ %I64d\n", llTimestamp);
        }
        else
        {
            WriteLogFile(L"video: @ %I64d\n", llTimestamp);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hrStatus))
            {
                    hrStatus = pSample->SetSampleTime(llTimestamp);
            }

            if (SUCCEEDED(hrStatus))
            {
                    hrStatus = pSample->SetSampleDuration(myVideoRecorder.CaptureParams.VIDEO_FRAME_DURATION);
            }

            // Send the sample to the Sink Writer.

            if (pWriter)
                if (SUCCEEDED(hrStatus))
                {

                    hrStatus = pWriter->WriteSample(streamIndex, pSample);
                }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**
Apparently, I was setting up sink writer to accept audio and video but only supplying video samples for now.  Supplying audio samples as well fixed it.

Comment: You'd better give [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).If necessary, give debugging information that will help people find problems.

Comment: You should check the timestamps that you supply in SetSampleTime

Comment: It's solved but thanks.

Comment: So what you where tying to say is that `WriteSample` blocks when the video frames are too far ahead of the audio